# How can I always display the map view callouts?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

How to always show the callouts in the map view? If we tap the map view callout hide and once again tap the pin its show. I don't want like this.., I need always showing the callout, without hide. How to do this. Please help me. I am using below code for show the callout. Its not working fine.

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:addAnnotation animated:NO];
annotationView.canShowCallout   = YES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can do this by using `delegate` method `didDeselectAnnotationView` of `MKMapView` and select the same `annotation` when it deselect like this -

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [mapView selectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:FALSE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callout is shown when an `MKAnnotationView` is selected and the view's `canShowCallout` property is set to `YES`.

It is then hidden when that `MKAnnotationView` is deselected. This occurs by tapping another annotation view, or by tapping outside of the currently selected annotation view.

As the delegate of `MKMapView` (conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate`), you are told when an annotation view is selected and deselected, but it's too late to do anything about it.

If you want to not deselect an annotation view, you should subclass `MKAnnotationView` and override the `setSelected:animated:` method and stop the annotation view from being deselected.

**EDIT:**

Remove this method if it is there in your code

```
- (void)deselectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Thanks Gill...Any other way to achieve this one.

Comment: I didn't use this method. I am only using viewForAnnotation delegate.